# Running function on only one host with Fabric

Tags: python, deployment, fabric

I'm having a task that does the following.

```
@task
def deploy():
    checkout():
    update_submodules()
    send_notification(env.server_type)
```

env.server_type defines whether the task is run on production or staging.

Is it possible to restrict the run on just one host for the send_notification function, like some form of overriding using parameters? Currently when the task is executed on multiple hosts, it sends notification for every host that it runs on, which is something I want to avoid. Any alternatives to this?

Comment: You mean you can have multiple hosts in staging and in production and you want to run send_notifications only on one of staging hosts?

Comment: @MichaelPlakhov Yeah, just send one notification rather number of production hosts

Comment: You can use env.host_string to detect which host is current, but i think you can use evn to store some custom flag variable like message_sent. env is kind of global scope, so you can send message when this env.message_sent is false and skip when it is true.